# Need to select from a dropdown in JSP and add the choice to an ArrayList

Tags: jsp, web-applications, jstl

I have a snippet where in I display the OptionName and the various options against it in a dropdown.

Now, I want to save all the selections made by the user in an `ArrayList` and then pass it on to another Servlet.

```
<form method="post" action="ComputePrice">
<table border="1">
    <TR>
        <c:forEach items="${optionSets}" var="optionSetLocal">
            <TD>${optionSetLocal}</TD>

            <TD><select name="myChoice">
            <d:forEach items="${rawData.get(optionSetLocal)}"
                        var="optionsLocal">
                        <option>${optionsLocal}</option>
                    </d:forEach>
                    <select onclick value="${choices.add(myChoice)}"></select>
            </select></TD>
    </TR>

    </c:forEach>


</table>
<input type="Submit" value="Ok" />
```

For now, when I print the `ArrayList` "choices" in the other Servlet, I get a set of all nulls. How can I populate the `ArrayList` with the choices made on the page?

For better knowledge of the code: optionSets is an `ArrayList`. rawData is a `LinkedHashMap` of as `<String, ArrayList>` where the hash is an entry in the optionSets arrayList.

I am not sure how to store the selections in the `ArrayList` so that I can use it for further processing in the next Servlet.

Tried attaching an image but wasn't able to due to insufficient points.

Comment: Why don't you pass the multiple selected values to your servlet through form submit? Adding the data to the arraylist should be one of your servlet's task when receiving POST request.

Comment: You can not pass Object like Arraylist,HashMap etc. using form submit. Store them in session or use hidden fields

Comment: @Med: How do I pass multiple selected values to the servlet? I would not know how many values are coming in the post to add all of them. It was my original plan to do that, but then I do not know how to count the number of values coming to the servlet.

Comment: Hardik: The arraylist is a session variable which is being used in the JSP. However, I want to get an array of selected values to the servlet.

Comment: Can't you simply use `request.getParameterValues()` to process the submitted form data from your servlet?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is an easy way or not. But try to add as much hidden fields equal to size of selection list. Set the field values using script when the select.
And in servlet you can get it.